# How to make a new Cosine Similarity function for document similarity

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I am trying to make a python function for the equations of cosine similarity as shown in the image below. I can easily make the function for the first equation but unable to get the second one correct. If someone can help me that would be great.

[image]

Here is the code for the first formula:

```
    def _cosine_sim(self, vecA, vecB):
        csim=( np.dot(vecA,vecB) )/(np.linalg.norm(vecA)*np.linalg.norm(vecB))
        if np.isnan(np.sum(csim)):
            return 0
        return csim
```

For the second formula, I have tried this but this is not working.

```
    def _cosine_sim(self, vecA, vecB):
        csim= (np.dot(vecA,vecB))**2 /( norm(vecA,2)**2 )*( norm(vecB,2)**2 )
        if np.isnan(np.sum(csim)):
            return 0
        return csim
```

Comment: "not working." - how?

Comment: It is giving me a similarity score of more than 1. Like 3.55, 2.03 etc